# Java Reference assignment with generic lists

Tags: java, generics, list, casting

I feel stupid asking this but I am.

The line `List<HasId> ids = list` is giving a compile error in the following code:

```
public class MyGarbageClass {

    public void myMethod(List<MyCompany> list){
        List<HasId> ids = list;
    }

    interface HasId {
        int getId();
    }
    class MyCompany implements HasId{
        private int id = 5;
        @Override
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

MyCompany implements HasId so I thought I should be able to assign it.  Why cant I?  And **more importantly**, what is an easy way to assign this to HasId list of objects.

**update**: List ids = `(List<HasId>)list;` breaks also on inconvertible types

Comment: that's also not a cast, that's a reference assignment. A cast would be something like int a = (int) b;

Comment: @Jeff Storey, I updated the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why generic assignment like this is disallowed is it possible to do the cast and then add something to `ids` which is not a MyCompany (perhaps MyPerson which also implements HasId).  So if the cast was allowed then you could do this.

```
public void myMethod(List<MyCompany> list){
    List<HasId> ids = list;
    ids.add(new MyPerson());
}
```

Now the list has broken the generic guarantee because you have list that was declared as `<MyCompany>` with a MyPerson in it.

You could cast it like this.

```
public void myMethod(List<MyCompany> list){
    List<? extends HasId> ids = list;
}
```

But add() operations will not be permitted, but you can iterate it to get the id if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

It's not allowed because it might allow you to do this:

```
List<MyCompany> companies = ...;
List<HasId> ids = companies;
ids.add(new HasId() {});
MyCompany c = companies.pop(); // <---- Not a MyCompany!!!!
```

You might find it better to use `List<? extends HasId>`

Answer (score 3):

It is **[typesafety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-type-safety-warning-in-certain-java-generics-casts)**.

```
List<HasId> ids ;
```

It is declared to accept only list of `HasId`.