# Why won't Java call the (List<Object>) method, if I have an (Object...) one?

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

I have the following class which stores a list of object arrays.

```
public class Test {
    private List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    public void addList(Object... obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public void addList(List<Object> lst) {
        list.add(lst.toArray());
    }
}
```

When I call the following, the overloaded method `addList(Object... obj)` is called but I want the `addList(List<Object> lst)` to be called. How can I do this?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test testObj = new Test();
        List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        myStrings.add("string 1");
        myStrings.add("string 2");
        myStrings.add("string 3");

        // The variable argument method is called but this is a list!
        testObj.addList(myStrings);

    }    
}
```

Comment: You should consider moving away from a `List<Object[]>` storage system. Whatever your data looks like, modeling it into classes and working with those will be much easier than trying to reason about a bunch of `Object`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `List<Object>` to `List<?>` to capture lists of any type of object. I tried this and it printed "in List":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    public void addList(Object... obj) {
        System.out.println("in object");
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public void addList(List<?> lst) {
        System.out.println("in List<?>");
        list.add(lst.toArray());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test testObj = new Test();
        List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        myStrings.add("string 1");
        myStrings.add("string 2");
        myStrings.add("string 3");

        // The variable argument method is called but this is a list!
        testObj.addList(myStrings);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's problem of Java Generic. You cannot assign `List<String>` to `List<Object>`.

See also: [Java Reference assignment with generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944826/java-reference-assignment-with-generic-lists)

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite the type of you non-variadic method to use a wildcard:

```
public void addList(List<?> lst) {
    list.add(lst.toArray());
}
```

Then `List<String>` will be a subtype of the parameter type.

Answer (score 6):

`List<String>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`.  So that overload will never be called, even if you remove the `...` variant.

Answer (score 2):

Change your method to

```
public void addList(List<?> lst) {
    list.add(lst.toArray());
}
```